# Area (length) of a submanifold of the sphere

Tags: real-analysis, integration, reference-request, geometric-measure-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^\infty$ function. Assume further that $\nabla f \neq 0$ on $\{f=0\} \neq \emptyset$. I would like to show that $$\mathscr H^1(f^{-1}(0))=  \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\int_{|f|<\epsilon} \chi(f(x)/\varepsilon)|\nabla f(x)|dS(x)$$ where $dS(x)$ is the natural measure on the sphere and $\chi \in C_c^\infty$ is a plateau/bump function that equals $1$ near $0$ (or any function that is constantly $1$ in a neighborhood of $0$).

---

For one, I know that $\{f=0\}$ is a finite union of circles (modulo diffeomorphism) because it is a compact manifold of dimension 1, and it would be enough to assume that it admits a single connected component.

Furthermore, I assume that we could invoke the implicit function theorem but I am not sure how.

P.S. If anyone could also provide a reference that involves the above formula, that would be great. I looked into Topics on Analysis in Metric Spaces by Ambrosio and Tilli but I could find none.

Comment: [Coarea formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula) is the name for this sort of computation; it works on Riemannian manifolds just as well as on Euclidean spaces. For example [here](https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Coarea.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! In all the references of GMT that I checked, I didn't see this formulation with the bump function. Do you maybe have a reference for that too?